# Parsing json array into an array of maps in react using Lodash

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-redux, lodash

Let's say this is how my json looks like and it contains an array:

```html
{ 
  "status": {
    "time": 175
  },
  "hits": [
    {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2"
    },
    {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2"
    },
    {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2"
    },
  ]
}
```

I want to create an array of maps like this in react:

```html
[ 
{mapkey1: value1, mapkey2: value2},
{mapkey1: value1, mapkey2: value2},
{mapkey1: value1, mapkey2: value2},
]
```

I already have a map of `mapkeys` to their xpaths in source json:

```html
{
 mapkey1: xpath1,
 mapkey2: xpath2
 }
```

How can I  parse this map into another array using Lodash?

I know how to do it when there is no array:

```html
_.mapValues(
 xpathsMap,
 paths => _.get(data, paths),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [
    {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2"
    },
    {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2"
    },
    {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2"
    },
  ];

var output = [];

_.forEach(arr, function(obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    var ob = {};

   _.forEach(keys, function(key) {
       ob['map' + key] = obj[key];
     })

    output.push(ob);
});

console.log(output);
```

This will give you the desired output -

```
[
    {mapkey1: "value1", mapkey2: "value2"},
    {mapkey1: "value1", mapkey2: "value2"},
    {mapkey1: "value1", mapkey2: "value2"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array of objects. Create the object keys you require, using lodash's [`_.mapKeys()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mapKeys):

```js
const data = {"status":{"time":175},"hits":[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]}

const result = data.hits.map((o) => _.mapKeys(o, (val, key) => `map${key}`));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```